# intersection of a line and plane on a 3-sphere

Tags: analytic-geometry, systems-of-equations, spherical-geometry

Suppose I have two 4D points, $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ and $\mathbf{b}=(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)$, that both lie on a unit 3-sphere (i.e. unit distance from origin). In addition, I have a 2-D plane that is formed by the intersection of $\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}=0$ ($\mathbf{p}$ is known) and the 3-sphere. I am trying to find the intersection of this plane and the unique "line" that passes through $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ within the 3-sphere (analogous to a great circle in spherical geometry). What system of equations would I solve to find this intersection?

Comment: The plane is the intersection of $x=0$, $y=0$ or $z=0$ with the 3-sphere?

Comment: I think you've left something out in the second line: what is the 3-sphere intersected with to create your 2D cross section?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason the editor dropped my expression for the dot product (maybe because I used angle brackets originally). The 3-sphere is intersected with a 3-D entity defined by p.x=0, where p is a known 4-D "pole."